# ConcurrentHashMap thread safety

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Is it thread safe to modify a concurrentHashMap of values ArrayList?
If not , what is the most efficient way to initialize and update an arraylist of ints inside a ConcurrentHashMap?

Thanks

Comment: Which of the objects can be updated by different threads - the map itself (adding/removing lists) or the lists inside the map? If it's the latter, then no, ConcurrentHashMap does not help you with that, you will need something like `java.util.Collections#synchronizedList(java.util.List<T>)` to make those lists thread safe.

Comment: Yes its the list that can be updated. So how can I use the above synchronization code while updating the list. Could you please provide a snippet demonstrating this?

Comment: As I wrote, just make sure that all `List`s inside your `ConcurrentHashMap` are created with `java.util.Collections#synchronizedList(java.util.List<T>)`, then it is thread safe at both levels (with the corresponding performance implications).

Answer (score 0):

There are two data structures that need thread-safety in your example.

One is the map, so any updates on the map need to be thread-safe which you have gotten covered.

Second one is the arrayList. You need to ask what is the expected behavior if multiple threads are looking to update the same arrayList. Arraylists throw ConcurrentModificationException in such a scenario which you wouldn't want.

You should put in Collections.synchronizedList or CopyOnWriteArrayList in the map in such a case. The latter is a better alternative if there aren't too many updates.